# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I installed django-allauth for adding user-accounts in my website. But I want to use local ID temporarily. I didn't follow the last three steps

> 1. Add a Site for your domain, matching settings.SITE_ID (django.contrib.sites app).
> 2. For each OAuth based provider, add a Social App (socialaccount app).
> 3. Fill in the site and the OAuth app credentials obtained from the provider.

But I got this problem when I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/:

```
    NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/   
    Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
    Django Version: 1.7.4
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    
    Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
    Exception Location: /home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 468
    Python Executable:  /home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/bin/python
    Python Version: 3.4.2
    Python Path:    
    ['/home/fyl00/Nutstore/pmdog',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_social_auth-0.8.1-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/python_social_auth-0.2.2-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests_oauthlib-0.3.1-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/python3_openid-3.0.5-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyJWT-0.4.1-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/oauthlib-0.7.2-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests-2.5.3-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/defusedxml-0.4.1-py3.4.egg',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/lib/python3.4',
     '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
     '/home/fyl00/.virtualenvs/pmdog/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
    Server time:    Fri, 13 Feb 2015 05:54:52 +0800
```

I tried the steps in https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/333 .
The output is:

```
>>> reverse('account_login')
'/accounts/login/'
>>> reverse('openid_login')
'/accounts/openid/login/'
```

Comment: Did you customize the login template? If yes, please post it. Also, you should still add SITE_ID to your settings.py even if you don't use social authentication.

Comment: @Selcuk I‘m using the default templates， so I didn't customize template. The problem still exist after I add SITE_ID to settings.py .